# how to get product image in autocomplete list in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Well my question is How I can get a product image just near the product title in my autocomplete list in magento.

I did many searches and most of answer are by adding this line of code:

```
    $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image');
```

but it doesnt work and give me as url of all product :

```
catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg
```

the function `getSuggestData()`:

```
public function getSuggestData()
{

if (!$this->_suggestData) {
    $collection = $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestCollection();
    $query = $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();
    $counter = 0;
    $data = array();
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image');          
      $_data = array(
            'title' => $item->getQueryText(),
            'row_class' => (++$counter)%2?'odd':'even',
            'num_of_results' => $item->getNumResults(),
            'url' => $imageUrl
        );

        if ($item->getQueryText() == $query) {
            array_unshift($data, $_data);
        }
        else {
            $data[] = $_data;
        }
    }



    $this->_suggestData = $data;
}
return $this->_suggestData;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: can you please tell me what is autocomplete list?

Comment: when you write something in the search input , a list appear with some products suggested to your search like the name mean it's autocomplete search

Comment: can you please tell me in which file location you have made this?

Comment: code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Autocomplete.php